# Xcode 7 broken font after El Capitan update

Tags: c++, xcode, fonts, osx-elcapitan

I've updated OSX some hours ago to El Capitan and the font of my Xcode c++ project started to create some problem.

[image]

As you can see the margin of the font are ok and you can barely read the text, but It should be white-filled; also I haven't changed nothing before the update.
I know that one of the El Capitan's new features is the new San Francisco font, but It shouldn't be used as a system font? Is there some fix I should do?

Thanks.

Comment: That looks like a rendering problem to me, as if the characters are rendered transparent on top of a buffer which has a black background and some white characters in it.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but the rgba value are correct...but if I try to change the color, the black text won't change, although the white text inside changes to the selected color.